# Styling individual radio buttons in drupal form

Tags: forms, drupal, element, styling

I have this group of radio buttons in which each of individual button has of its own position set through style attribute. I would like to how can I archive the same by using drupal form api. I found how to style as whole but, not as individual control within group. Here's how my html code look like -

```
<input type="radio" name="base_location" checked="checked" value="0" style="margin-left:70px;float:left;"/><span style="float:left;">District</span>
  <input type="radio" name="base_location" value="1" style="margin-left:50px;float:left;"/><span style="float:left;">MRT</span>
  <input type="radio" name="base_location" value="2" style="margin-left:60px;float:left;"/><span style="float:left;">Address</span>
```

And this is the drupal code I'm stuck at -

```
$form['base_location'] = array(
   '#type' => 'radios',
   '#title' => t('base location'),
   '#default_value' => variable_get('search_type', 0),
   '#options' => array(
'0'=>t('District'),
'1'=>t('MRT'),
'2'=>t('Address')),
   '#description' => t('base location'),
```

I'm aware of #type=>radio existence. However, I do not know how to group all my radio buttons together in this regard. If I use same array key for all of them, they would collide each other. If I don't, they aren't seen as part of the same group. I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Drupal 6.x Form API and `#type=>radios` (http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_radios/6) each radio element will have its unique id which you can use to apply proper CSS.

The example you provided

```
$form['base_location'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => t('base location'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('search_type', 0),
  '#options' => array(
  '0'=>t('District'),
  '1'=>t('MRT'),
  '2'=>t('Address')),
  '#description' => t('base location'),
);
```

should output markup like so:

```
<div id="base-location-0-wrapper" class="form-item">
  <label for="base-location-0" class="option"><input type="radio" class="form-radio" value="0" name="base_location" id="base-location-0"> District</label>
</div>
<div id="base-location-1-wrapper" class="form-item">
  <label for="base-location-1" class="option"><input type="radio" class="form-radio" value="1" name="base_location" id="base-location-1"> MRT</label>
</div>
<div id="base-location-2-wrapper" class="form-item">
  <label for="base-location-2" class="option"><input type="radio" class="form-radio" value="2" name="base_location" id="base-location-2"> Address</label>
</div>
```

Apply the following CSS and you should be set.

```
  #base-location-0-wrapper,
  #base-location-1-wrapper,
  #base-location-2-wrapper {
    display:inline;
    margin-left:50px;
  }
```

Comment: Except an ID is sometimes not reliable between environments. For example if the radios are generated from taxonomy terms, you could get <taxonomy_name>-tid-<number> which cannot reliably be used.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use CSS with the html that you already have. It looks like you just want to change the radio buttons' display to 'inline' with 10px margins, which you can do. (And if you did break the radios up into separate elements within a fieldset, they'd no longer interact with each other.)

Comment: I think I'm stuck with markup type and write the corresponding html code directly. But I'm not sure if drupal would still see them as controls. Would it?

Comment: Why are you stuck with 'markup type'? Output the form with Drupal and style it with CSS. Where's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I didn't know drupal generate id on its own for each element and, the only way I could think of to archive what I want is, to output markup as it is and assigned class or set style for each element. But, now it's clear; all I need is - define css style with drupal generated ids. Thanks anyway.